# Reference from python into kivy gone wrong

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

The problem is in the .kv file. My problem is that i would like my .kv to notice the object-property in my .py. My code works if change the color in .kv to `color: 0,0,0` which gives me black text as intend.

.py

```
from kivy import utils
from kivy.animation import Animation 
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import ButtonBehavior

Builder.load_file("FirebaseLoginScreen/themedwidgets.kv")

class ThemedButton(ButtonBehavior,Label):
    colorchanged = ObjectProperty()
    color = ObjectProperty([0,0,0,1])
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ThemedButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.start_pulsing, 1)

    def start_pulsing(self, *args):
        anim = Animation(color=[0,1,0,1]) + Animation(color=[0,0,1,1]) + Animation(color=[1,0,0,1]) 
        anim.repeat = True
        anim.start(self)
```

.kv

```
<ThemedButton@ButtonBehavior+Label>:
    colorchanged: colorchanged
    id: colorchanged
    markup: True
    color: self.color #root.color doesn't work either but 0,0,0 does give me black. 
    opacity: 1 if self.state == 'normal' else .8
    font_size: 38
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ThemedButton@ButtonBehavior+Label>:
```

This is the kv syntax to create a *new* widget class inheriting from ButtonBehavior and Label, so it doesn't have any of the behaviour of your Python-defined class that happens to have the same name.

You want to just do `<ThemedButton>:` instead.